# Please help - error: Ignoring file 'pg' in directory

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Good day, i am trying to install postgresql and pgadmin on my ubuntu 20.04... i was stocked with this error when i run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

error:

```
N: Ignoring file 'pg' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

i tried to solve it with this line of code:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

but it threw back this error:

```
(gedit:17048): Tepl-WARNING **: 17:10:16.344: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.
```

Now i don't know how else to fix this. Any help?

Comment: Try using a different text editor.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: But the error should be different. You don't get a gedit error when using nano or vim.

Comment: Please how can i delete the file to start again?

Comment: See `man rm` for how to delete files. WARNING: No undo. `rm` is permanent, so be very sure before you use it. No typos.

Answer (score 1):

To use the PostgreSQL Apt Repository in Ubuntu 20.04 follow these steps:

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` with `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && sudo touch pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository.

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
   ```
2. Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists.

   ```
   wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt update
   ```

Comment: or `echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` for the first step